# How to know if the pickup and the drop off land on different cities in android google map

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I'm building an uber like application, I want to know if there is a way to check if the pickup and the drop off land on different cities in android google map.

Comment: I don't think there is an API to check whether if 2 locations are in diff cities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to use the [Geocoding API by Google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start#reverse) to reverse geocode the coordinates of your pickup and drop off locations to find out which city they belong to.

From the Geocoding API documentation linked above:

Reverse geocoding is the process of converting geographic coordinates into a human-readable address.

Comment: Actually, I did this, but some cities have different names in the same area, it will require me to handle a lot of if conditions

Comment: I've yet to encounter that, but parsing the API responses is up to you. The `formatted_address` and `address_components` keys are usually sufficient, perhaps you can use the `locality` type in the `address_components` array to best approximate for your needs.


For all the types the API provides: [See Types](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Types)

Comment: @Galalen consider adding whatever you have tried so far to the original question to better help others to help you.

Comment: I think your last comment is the appropriate answer, thanks dud